# Something which is not intellectual is visceral?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> Some people argue that poverty and misbehave go hand in hand, but I
> think that this view is more visceral rather than being intellectually
> based on  facts.

Did I use the word "visceral" correctly in this sentence? I want to say that some people just say this because they feel so, they do not have any reason to support their claim.

Comment: Misbehave is a verb, not a noun.

Comment: I have a visceral dislike of the sight of spilled blood, or of the thought of torture. My views about poverty and (I guess) criminality are political, and 'visceral' would be an inaccurate and dismissive adjective to apply to them.

Comment: misbehavior: Please don't ask us to proofread anymore.

Comment: You can simply say "I think some people *feel* that ..." and then cut off the second part altogether...

Comment: @Lambie This isn't a proofreading request. As the close flag reads: "*Questions asking for someone to **find and correct errors** or **improve the phrasing** are considered requests for proofreading and are off-topic. Please edit your question to focus on **something in particular** that you are unsure about*". The question focuses on uncertainty about the correct usage of the word "visceral". The OP has also given the meaning of "visceral" that they intend. The OP did not ask us to find errors or to improve their phrasing.

Comment: @gotube I am entitled to my opinion.

Comment: @Lambie You are entitled to your opinion, but you are not entitled to tell users that their on-topic questions are off-topic. Also, assuming you close-voted, you're not entitled to vote questions closed that are on-topic according to the text in the flag.

Comment: @gotube Questions that can be answered by a quick dictionary lookup (these are off topic on ELL, and there are many free dictionaries available online. If you are asking about the meaning of a word or phrase, you should look up those words in a dictionary first. If you are still confused, **be sure to summarize what you found when you did your initial research, and summarize that information in the question**.) Please stop lecturing me, I would appreciate it. This is not the first time.

Comment: @Lambie I agree that *this* flag has merit. But the only flag currently raised is about proofreading, as was your comment. I'm sorry you feel I'm lecturing you -- again. I'm legit just trying to keep flags and comments fair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visceral means the instinctive *gut* feeling (viscera is the name for the cavities in the body, especially the intestines)

> He has a visceral fear of spiders.

I don't think this is the right word.  I think that you might say that the connection between poverty and crime is a "common-sense notion" or a "folk belief", or even an "urban myth", and it isn't supported by evidence.

Comment: "it isn't supported by evidence." - that would be [a matter of opinion](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2021/apr/22/the-guardian-view-on-poverty-and-speaking-truth-to-priti-patel).

Comment: I think that is the opinion that the OP is intending.  They state that the view point is not "based on facts", which seems to make their view clear.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of *visceral* falls well within one of its basic meanings, specifically,

[Merriam-Wester *visceral*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visceral)

> 2 : not intellectual : instinctive, unreasoning visceral drives

and
[American Heritage Dictionary *visceral*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=visceral)

> 2. Being or arising from impulse or sudden emotion rather than from thought or deliberation

and
[Collins *visceral*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/visceral)

> Visceral feelings are feelings that you feel very deeply and find it difficult to control or ignore, and that are not the result of thought.